# How do you copy one column in one sheet to another column in a different sheet, while skipping over blank cells?

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet, copy-paste

I have a one sheet with a column which ranges from C2 till C6115. In that range there are many empty cells. I want to copy the filled cells only into a seperate sheet using VB in excel 2007. Can anyone give me a general code that can help me perform that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub copy()
Dim i As Long
Dim cell As Range
i = 1
For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("c2:c6115")
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        Sheets(2).Range("c" & i).Value = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: This code copys to the proper destination but it doesnt copy the correct column, it copied random information from column B.

Comment: I tested it before write here and it copies not empty cells within the range c2:c6115 from sheet1 into column c of sheet 2. I don't know why you have this weird behaviour.